# Routing to different mysql datasource master/slave in a springboot application using spring jpa and reading properties from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, master-slave, application.properties

Routing to different mysql datasource master/slave in a springboot application using spring jpa and reading properties from application.properties

How should i route to different databases in a spring application

I am using AbstractRoutingDatasource spring library

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it helped. Also, please do read : [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

AbstractRoutingDatasource requires information to know which actual DataSource to route to. This information is provided by implementing determineCurrentLookupKey() abstract function. You can configure this method to provide key from your properties file.

```
@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return "property from file";
}
```

You will also need a map of DataSource objects to configure AbstractRoutingDataSource and a default DataSource to use if there is no context set. Then you can configure your DataSource something like this :

```
Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
DataSource slaveDatasource = slaveDatasource();
DataSource masterDatasource = masterDatasource();
targetDataSources.put("slave", slaveDatasource);
targetDataSources.put("master", masterDatasource);
DataSourceRouter routingDatasource = new DataSourceRouter();
routingDatasource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
routingDatasource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(someDefaultDataSource);
return routingDatasource;
```

Reference link : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source